# SQL Server 2012 SP 1 - Insert Permissions On Filetable

Tags: permissions, sql-server-2012, filetable

I am new to SQL server filetable, so I'm trying to get a grasp on how the table permissions affect the file share.  What I am looking to do is to allow users to read and create/add files to the file share, but not allow them to update or delete files that already exist.

From what I have read, I should be able to just grant SELECT and INSERT permissions to the users to get this functionality, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

The only way I can get users to be able to create/add files to the file share is if I grant UPDATE permissions, which also gives them the ability to update existing files.

Is this consistent with what other people have experienced?  Is it possible to get the functionality that I am looking for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had share permission issues and found that I needed Select, Insert and Update to be granted.

I found that if I turned any one of those permissions off, that I would not be able to create a file. See:

[Access Denied when inserting file into Sql Server 2012 FileTable using File.CreateFile in ASP.NET website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023684/access-denied-when-inserting-file-into-sql-server-2012-filetable-using-file-crea)