# Insert filetable using fileupload from local

Tags: sql-server, filetable

I have some basic question about filetable.

1. How do I upload file from local to server(directly to filetable directory)?
   I have tried, but error 'access denied to xxx path' was popped up
2. When I try to insert filetable using sql command (BULK insert 'filestream'), it did say the path was not found.

What I have tried so far:

1. I have granted user from appPool permission to access filetable db
   ([grant access filetable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023684/access-denied-when-inserting-file-into-sql-server-2012-filetable-using-file-crea))
2. I have enable filestream remote access client in sql server config
3. I have set non-transactional setting in options tab in filetable db properties to 'full'

**the error message when I'm using fileupload to move file from local to filetable directory on server**

```
Access to the path '\\BHPREPOSRV\testSLA\LET THE MUSIC HEAL Y.mp3.jpg' is denied.
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a couple of the components of the file table UNC path.  In addition to the server name, the path must include the instance FILESTREAM share name, database FILESTREAM directory, and file table name.

```
\\server-name\instance-filestream-share\database-filestream-directory\file-table-name\LET THE MUSIC HEAL Y.mp3.jpg
```