# Accessing to SQL Server Filetable from IIS APP POOL

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, filetable

I have an ASP.Net MVC application which is published on the IIS server,in this app I want to access the files which are stored in the filetable of a database,I mean I'm trying to access the files stored in the virtual filetable directory.
Note:The application and database are located **on different servers**.
Currently, I receive *"Access to the path denied"* in my application.
I don't know how to set the proper login and permission to achieve this goal.

Please help me solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

maybe these help

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1838/different-ways-to-enable-filestream-feature-of-sql-server-2008/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492061.aspx

[Access Denied when inserting file into Sql Server 2012 FileTable using File.CreateFile in ASP.NET website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023684/access-denied-when-inserting-file-into-sql-server-2012-filetable-using-file-crea)

Comment: Thanks a lot,but I've checked these links before and they didn't help.

Comment: Many years on and I need an answer to this question also. If anyone knows how to get this working, please share. I need to write files to the UNC share exposed by MS SQL's FileTable from a C# website hosted on the same server. Any help would be greatly appriciated. Thank you.