# File Table (SQL Server 2016) FILESTREAM permissions lost in IIS

Tags: iis, sql-server-2016, filetable

[image: This is an example of an image displayed in Chrome through a site, and just rendering a local html file. IIS lost the ability to display the image from the file system provided by SQL]
[image: File representation and database representation]
[image: Exception in Process Monitor]
[image: An image displaying the user with access denied, showing the same user IS the application pool user, and db_owner memebership, and SELECT on FileTable permission]

I am trying to store images in a FileTable that is accessible from a website.
According to my understanding, the FileTable needs "SELECT" granted to the account running ApplicationPool that the website runs in.

Example of what I have:

- IIS (6.2)
- Application pool user : Domain\Bob.
- SQL Server login Domain\Bob
- Database has `Domain\Bob` in `db_owner` group. I explicitly granted `Domain\Bob` select on the file table also.
- `DB.dbo.FileStream_FileTable` is `\\DEV\FileStream_FileTable\`
- IIS has SiteA
- SiteA has virtual directory `Image` targeting `\\127.0.0.1\DEV\FileStream_FileTable\`

If I look at the IIS authentication, IIS errors saying insufficient permission to access `web.config` - but there is no `web.config`.

On the server, running Internet Explorer, referencing an image as `\\127.0.0.1\DEV\FileStream_FileTable\<...>\Image1.jpg` it resolves to the jpg.

On the server, running Internet Explorer, referencing an image as `HTTP://127.0.0.1/SiteA/Image/Image1.jpg`, IE errors (same error as the authentication error)...

> Config Error
>   Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
>
> Config File
>   \?\UNC\127.0.0.1\dev\ItemImage\web.config

There IS no config file.

I have tried specifying the Windows user (Domain\Bob) context when accessing the virtual folder "Images" targetting \127.0.0.1\DEV\Filestream_FileTable 
and also not specifying the windows credential...

I do not understand why the Image is visible using the UNC path in Internet Explorer (it must authenticate my context as having select on the filestream_filetable table) but not when using the context specifying a Windows context of a user who also has select on the table, in IIS.

NOTE: As an experiment, I modified the user, in IIS, used to access the share to Administrator. Then the IIS site resolved the image.

(Virtual directory targetting the \\servername\sql_instance_filestream_handle\directory\tablename)

The Windows User Domain\Bob has full rights on database - database owner.

There is another user's question, [Access to SQL Server FileTable from IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153837/access-to-sql-server-filetable-from-iis), that has servername in file share being a potential issue if the IIS and SQL server is on the same host, which I have taken into consideration.

I have added Domain\Bob to IIS_ISURS group...

What is Domain\Bob not a member of that grants access? 
I can't very well make all my IIS shares accessing with Administrator accounts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some case, IIS will try to create web.config if the UNC path just return access denied error. If IIS failed to create web.config, It will also fail to access web.config with 500.19.

So please ensure your Application pool identity is set to a domain account who have read/write permission to access the folder.

Then please try to set Anonymous authentication->edit..->Application pool identity.

Comment: Thanks for your response @jokies. I have made the application pool user member of db_owner and SQL is presenting the share, therefore controls access? 
I have set the site virtual folder accessing the share to use the domain account, in advanced settings.

Comment: @Alocyte Have you set both NTFS permission and network share access for your domain account?

Comment: In computer management/ shared folders/ shares I have explicitly granted Domain\Bob full permission on the share.
The SQL managed share, stored on the file system as F:\Catalyst$DEV\images\content\cc9f5495-bb4e-4c6d-a190-7ef66e6c44e5 - this I have also granted Domain\Bob read access. I know this is the folder because the file count matches my row count in the FileTable.

Comment: Please try process monitor and add a filter for "result=access denied". It should help you fix this.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: I amended my question to include the result of the process monitor. Again, this is the Access Denied issue - but the application pool account, the database login, and file system level access for that "user account" is allowing read. The same result occurs after I grant Domain\Bob FULL rights on the folder SQL presents as the share.

Comment: @Alocyte.Please double click the line "createfile". It should show the real user.

Comment: Jokies - i amended my question to include the user the Process Monitor shows is getting Access Denied - it is Domain\Bob My image includes the application pool identity (Domain\Bob) and Domain\Bob permission on the database.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows user Domain\Bob was not a login in the DEV sql instance.
Creating a sql login solved it. *blush*

Database level had the user, yes, but the SQL server didn't have a login.

## facepalm

Comment: It is appreicated if you could accept your reply as answer. Thanks!

Comment: So please ensure your Application pool identity is set to a domain account who have read/write permission to access the folder.
This, your original statement - is the answer. Thanks @JokiesDing